# rewrite urls , not all urls works

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have blog and I want to rewrite the link

`site.com/blog` -> for the blog index `blog_posts.php`

`site.com/blog/{post-slug}` -> for the `single_post.php?post-slug={post-slug}`

`site.com/blog/topic/{topic}` -> for the `filtered_posts.php?topic={topic}`

my problem is when I access to a post or a topic its access to `site.com/blog` blog_posts.php

I think because when access to `blog_posts.php` and write after it any think like `kbjsflgjdouihaiufhslkdf` access to `blog_posts.php`

my try

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Zأ-ي-]+)/ single_post.php?post-slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/ blog_posts.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/topic/([0-9a-zA-Zأ-ي-]+)/ filtered_posts.php?topic=$1 [NC,L]
```

and if there are any thing that tech all about the .htaccess please gimme a link

Comment: Is `/blog` a physical directory on the filesystem? You mention `blog_posts.php`, but none of your directives use this? You also have a rule that rewrites `/blog/<anything>` to `news.php` which is not mentioned in your criteria?

Comment: oh sorry didn't relaized it, now I edited the code `new.php` means  `blog_posts.php` but to be understandable I write it as a blog 
I didn't get your question **Is /blog a physical directory on the filesystem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Zأ-ي-]+)/ single_post.php?post-slug=$1 [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^blog/ blog_posts.php [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^blog/topic/([0-9a-zA-Zأ-ي-]+)/ filtered_posts.php?topic=$1 [NC,L]
> ```

You need to change the order of the directives and/or make the regex more specific. Order is important - the most specific regex need to be first.

For instance, your first rule `^blog/([0-9a-zA-Zأ-ي-]+)/` will naturally match any URL of the form `/blog/topic/<something>`, so the request is rewritten to `single_post.php` and the 3rd rule is never processed.

And your 2nd rule (`^blog/`), matches anything else that simply starts `/blog`, so again, the 3rd rule would never be processed.

Your example URLs, eg `/blog/{post-slug}` do not include a slash suffix, however, the directives you have written look as if you are trying to match one? Although you are not using any end-of-string anchor on the regex, so you are probably matching too much. For instance, the regex `^blog/([0-9a-zA-Zأ-ي-]+)/` will match a URL of the form `/blog/{post-slug}/1234/something/etc` which is probably not the intention (if it is the intention then it's still a fault as you potentially have a duplicate content issue).

I'm assuming your URLs are as per your example - no trailing slash.

I also queried (in comments) whether `/blog` a physical directory on the filesystem? If it is then your first example URL, ie. `/blog` is not canonical since mod_dir will implicitly trigger a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash. I'm assuming this is a physical directory and the canonical URL is actually `/blog/`, not `/blog`.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/topic/([0-9a-zA-Zأ-ي-]+)$ filtered_posts.php?topic=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Zأ-ي-]+)$ single_post.php?post-slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ blog_posts.php [L]
```

I also remove the `NC` (`nocase`) flag. You are already checking for both lowercase and uppercase letters in the regex, but if you are also allowing uppercase letters in other parts of the URL then you potentially have a duplicate content (non-canonical) URL issue that would need to be resolved.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: it works but why GET request `post-slug` don't work

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? What is the actual URL being requested?

Comment: `test.com/blog/slug` I opened this link everything all right but only I can't get the slug to search for the post

Comment: With the directives above, a request for `/blog/slug` would be internally rewritten to `single-post.php?post-slug=slug` - is that expected? If you "can't then get the slug to search for the post" then that would seem to be a problem with your `single_post.php` script?

Comment: `single-post.php?post-slug=slug` work, `blog/slug` don't work

Comment: So, `$_GET['post-slug']` is not set inside your PHP script, but it is successfully rewritten to `single-post.php`?

Comment: yup , what if I get the link and deleted `https://domain/blog/` and get the slug , is it a good idea ?

Comment: Well, you can do that. However, if `post-slug` is not set then something else is going on that may need to be fixed. Presumably the `topic` URL param is set in the case of `/blog/topic/{topic}` URLs? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? If so, add your complete `.htaccess` file to your question - there may be a conflict.

Comment: I hate my self man , I wrote `post-topic` instead of `post-slug`, thank you